# Issues on saving data from CPT select metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, select

I can't save data from a select metabox. My code is

http://pastebin.com/BMmKzti2

Where I'm going wrong?

Edit:

Here is my code

```
    function fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box', 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce' );
    $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key', true );
    $selecionargeracao = isset( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field['_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key'] ) ? esc_attr( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field['_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key'][0] ) : '';

    echo '<div class="unidadeelementotopovtm"><label for="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field">';
    _e( 'Geração:', 'fichasvtmbasicas_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<select id="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field" name="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field">';
    echo '<option value="geracao15"' . selected( $selecionargeracao['_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key'], '15' ) . '>15</option>';
    echo '<option value="geracao14"' . selected( $selecionargeracao['_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key'], '14' ) . '>14</option>';
    echo '<select>';
    echo '</div>';
    }

    function fichasvtmbasicas_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
            return;
    }
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce'], 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box' ) ) {
            return;
    }
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                    return;
            }

    } else {

            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                    return;
            }
    }
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field'] ) ) { //para Geração
            return;
    }
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key', esc_attr ( $_POST[ 'fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field' ] )); //para Geração
    }

    add_action( 'save_post', 'fichasvtmbasicas_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Edit:

I changed my code for

```
function fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box', 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce' );
$selecionargeracao = isset( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field['fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field'] ) ? esc_attr( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field['fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field'][0] ) : '';
echo '<div class="unidadeelementotopovtm"><label for="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field">';
_e( 'Geração:', 'fichasvtmbasicas_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<select id="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field" name="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field">';
echo '<option value="geracao15"' . selected( $selecionargeracao, '15' ) . '>15</option>';
echo '<option value="geracao14"' . selected( $selecionargeracao, '14' ) . '>14</option>';
echo '<select>';
echo '</div>';

function fichasvtmbasicas_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
if ( ! isset( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
    return;
}

// Verify that the nonce is valid.
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce'], 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box' ) ) {
    return;
}

// If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}

// Check the user's permissions.
if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

} else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
}
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field'] ) ) { //para Geração
    return;
}
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field', esc_attr ( $_POST[ 'fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field' ] ));
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'fichasvtmbasicas_save_meta_box_data' );
```

but still can't save my data. I have more metaboxes on the same function and they are saving the data, just the select don't save it.

Comment: Please add all the relevant code directly to your question. Do not use pastebin. The problem is, if that paste is removed, your question will be useless to others. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Now I have the code

```
function fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box', 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce' );
$fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key', true );

echo '<div class="unidadeelementotopovtm"><label for="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field" class="topodaficha_titles">';
_e( 'Geração:', 'fichasvtmbasicas_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<select id="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field" name="fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field">';
echo '<option value="decima-quinta" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'decima-quinta' ) . '>15ª</option>';
echo '<option value="decima-quarta" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'decima-quarta' ) . '>14ª</option>';
echo '<option value="decima-terceira" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'decima-terceira' ) . '>13ª</option>';
echo '<option value="decima-segunda" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'decima-segunda' ) . '>12ª</option>';
echo '<option value="decima-primeira" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'decima-primeira' ) . '>11ª</option>';
echo '<option value="decima" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'decima' ) . '>10ª</option>';
echo '<option value="nona" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'nona' ) . '>9ª</option>';
echo '<option value="oitava" ' . selected( $fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field, 'oitava' ) . '>8ª</option>';
echo '<select>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Then

```
function fichasvtmbasicas_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
if ( ! isset( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
    return;
}
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box_nonce'], 'fichasvtmbasicas_meta_box' ) ) {
    return;
}
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
}
if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

} else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
}

if ( ! isset( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field'] ) ) { //para Geração
    return;
}

$vtmbasica_geracao = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['fichasvtmbasicas_geracao_field'] ); //para Geração
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_vtmbasica_geracao_value_key', $vtmbasica_geracao ); //para Geração
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'fichasvtmbasicas_save_meta_box_data' );
```

And it's solved now. It can be useful for someone.